# Would I level up if I "automatically defeated" a monster but someone wandered in a monster that killed me afterwards?

Tags: munchkin

This question arises when we saw this in the FAQ:

> Q. I used an ability to automatically kill a monster. Another player used Wandering Monster to add a monster to the fight, and then played Transferal Potion to move the monster to himself. He beat it. Who gets the level and Treasures for the monster I killed?
>
> A. You do; you killed it. (This has been ruled different ways at different times, but we got a ruling directly from Steve, so it trumps everything else.) You get your level and Treasures after the whole combat is resolved.

Say for example in Zombies, Player A was a Level 9 Atomic Zombie (and therefore had flaming hands). He kicks open the door to find a Mascot which he automatically defeats with fire. Someone wanders in an Action Hero, which for the sake of argument ultimately kills Player A.

Would the combat resolve as "Player A goes up to Level 10 and then gets killed." or "Player A gets killed and doesn't level up." because of the "after the WHOLE combat is resolved" clause?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The Mascot is defeated, but Player A must defeat (but not necessarily kill) the wandering monster before being awarded levels or treasure (or the win).**

Basically, the rules state that after you kick open a door, you give a "[reasonable time](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/#combat)" to allow other players to intervene.

In the FAQ, the following Q/A answers your question:

> Q. Does the "reasonable time rule" apply to defeating a monster
>   without killing it, or just to killing it?
>   A. Any sort of defeat. **If
>   you defeat it without killing it, other players still have a
>   reasonable time to play an applicable card to frustrate you.** However,
>   if you removed the only monster from the fight (with Magic Lamp, for
>   instance), they cannot play Monster Enhancers or other similar cards
>   that affect a specific monster, because there isn't one there to
>   fight, and they can't use any special rules for bringing in monsters
>   (such as the Shark rules from Munchkin Booty) that depend on having a
>   monster in the fight. **They can play Wandering Monster to bring in an
>   entirely new monster, though, but they must do it at once.**

Basically, any ability that will auto-defeat the door mob still grants your opponents a "reasonable time" to respond, in which they can Wander in any monster they choose, which you have to fight *just* the additional monster.

Per this [Super Moderator](http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?t=87552) in the MunchkinForums:

> Automatically defeating a Monster removes the Monster. Cards that rely
>   on a Monster can't be played, but that doesn't mean that combat is
>   over UNLESS the card that automatically defeated the Monster says
>   otherwise. This is a situation where cards could be played, but not
>   those that affected a non-existent Monster.

As far as why your other outcome couldn't happen, "Player A goes up to Level 10 and then gets killed":

Per the [Munchkin Zombies ruleset](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/zombies_rules.pdf):

> 3. You cannot collect rewards for defeating a monster (e.g., Treasure, levels) in the middle of a combat. You must finish the fight before gaining any rewards.

And finally, this gets spelled out in the FAQ, Important Note #3:

> "Killed" means that you defeated the monster with your Level and
>   bonuses in combat, or used some card or special ability that
>   specifically states that it kills the monster. For this, you get
>   levels and Treasure. **Some Monsters say that they can be defeated
>   immediately, based on circumstances. Unless the card says otherwise,
>   this usually means an instant kill of the Monster, so you would get
>   levels and Treasure in those situations, too.** However, even in a case
>   where a single monster is instantly defeated, other players get a
>   chance to play Wandering Monster to add a new foe that you must defeat
>   before claiming the spoils.

TLDR; defeating (or auto-defeating) a monster does not end combat; the monster is removed, but other players have a "reasonable time" to play any such as wandering monster--if done at once.

Should all additional monsters be defeated (or lamped, etc.), combat is then resolved and you can claim victory with the kill granted by your auto-defeated monster.